# What can I do to get canvas working in different browsers

Tags: canvas, web-audio-api

I'm trying to get a nice looking radio for my website and everything works well for chrome (mostly). But this code doesn't work in firefox or edge. I believe canvas itself is working as my web page has a black background and everything but chrome shows white. It's just canvas isn't doing anything like it should.

What can I do to fix it?

The following is everything to do with the canvas. It pulls the song from the HTML audio element and proceeds to create an audio visualizer.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/radio.css">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <p class="songName" id="songName"></p>
  <audio id="playMusic" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
         <source id="source" src="" type="audio/mp3">
         Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
  <button class="skip" id="skip" style="position: absolute;" onclick="skip()">Skip Song</button>
  <br />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/radio.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce in Firefox 65.0.2 for Windows. Dynamic analyser output is shown on the canvas playing a local mp3 file with no change to the posted code. Please show the HTML you tried.

Comment: It worked in Edge as well when I tried it. The problem seems to be with something you haven't posted. Please review the help center article on "[How to create a minimum complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: My server crashed and I was unable to get the code. I've updated with the codes I currently use for this project.

Comment: Question tagged [javascript] without a single line of js. No this is not "everything to do with the canvas", but almost nothing to do with it. And above all, there is no description of the problem, you are only asking how to fix it. How do you want us to be able to fix something we don't know how it is broken?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the issue I had faced. 
Having an empty 'src=""' caused an error with edge and firefox, but not chrome, where it would fail to load the canvas.

```
<source id="source" src="" type="audio/mp3">//Results in an error loading media because there is no source.
```

Comment: No, what the quote is talking about is `src` **dynamically** set to the empty string `""`, that is by js, either using `imgNode.src = ""` or `imgNode.setAttribute('src', "");`. Beside, that your node has no src must be a problem for Chrome too. But since you didn't explain what is the problem you are facing, it's impossible for us to help you.